# Passing info from channel to channel while altering it in go

Tags: go, channel

I'm new to the go programming language.
I just learned about channels from their website, and tried to create
The following program:
1) I want to create 100,000 channels.
2) when the first channel receives a msg (value) he adds 1 to it
 and pass it on to the next channel (by order).
3) when we'll get to the last channel it Will print 100,001.

I have created the channels with a loop, but I find it difficult to find
how to pass and alter the data in a "domino" fashion like I described.
Any solution or reference would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
package main

func addOneAndPass(c1 chan int, c2 chan int)  {
    c := make(chan int)
    c <- 1
    val := <- c
}

func main() {
    const n = 100000
    var channels [n]chan int
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        channels[i] = make(chan int)
    }

}
```

Comment: Show what you tried so far.

Comment: I wrote exactly what I did correctly (creating the channels) and where I'm stuck (writing a function that will pass information from channel to channel by order and will increment the passed value by one.

Comment: Don't make us guess what code you wrote from your prose.  Show the code.

Comment: Uploaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://play.golang.org/p/ku-Dretm8EA

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func add1(in chan int) (chan int)  {
    i := <-in
    out := make(chan int, 1)
    out <- (i+1)
    return out
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    ch <- 1
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        ch = add1(ch)
    }
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

another solution: https://play.golang.org/p/uWVxSG0xgqU

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func add1(in, out chan int)  {
    i := <-in
    out <- (i+1)
}

func main() {
    start := make(chan int)
    var in = start
    var ch chan int
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        ch = make(chan int)
        go add1(in, ch)
        in = ch
    }
    start <- 1
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

Comment: Add a description explaining why these solutions work: they create a goroutine that receives a value, increments the value and sends it to the next channel.